# Javascript regex match same char is existed beside

Tags: javascript, regex, string, pattern-matching

I need to detect if multiple slashes exist besides.

/string///string//string/string

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = "/string///string//string/string";
var pattern = new RegExp("/");
var result = pattern .test(str);

console.log(result );
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: How does this find repeated slashes, as OP asked?